# How can I restore old posts after merging a Facebook Page with a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I merged a Facebook app and page a few months ago. The merge finished, but we lost a lot of content.

The strange thing is that the "lost" content is still appearing on our iframe widget, but not the Facebook page.

- **Facebook page**: http://www.facebook.com/dabball
- **Website with iframe widget**: dabball.com
- **iframe widget URL**: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fapps%2Fapplication.php%3Fid%3D171983012847806&width=360&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=white&stream=true&header=false&height=484

The outcome I'm looking for is to see all of the posts from September 2011 through December 2012 in our Facebook page, facebook.com/dabball

Is this something that Facebook can help with?

Answer (score 0):

Hopes you read the fb note when merging the page that your all posts lost of duplicate page 
and you can store the wall post using facebook app but there is no restore option and if using timeline page than you can do something which fulfills your need you can post your all previous post with the date of the post through app or you can post manually and change its date i suggests post manually as i think you just need to post maximum previous 5 days post because all the previous post is automatically hide but people can see them by scrolling down

Comment: Hi Danish, I'm sorry but I didn't understand. Is there a way to recover the old posts from the previous page?